# Create a new slide in VBA for PowerPoint 2010 with custom layout using Master

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I have the following VBA code to create a new PowerPoint slide:

```
longSlideCount = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

With ActivePresentation.Slides
    Set slideObject = .Add(longSlideCount + 1, ppLayoutTitle)
End With
```

...which inserts a new slide of type 'ppLayoutTitle', but I am wondering if it is possible to create a custom layout in the 'Slide Master View' and then insert **that** particular slide template into the presentation?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All your custom layouts can be accessed via VBA through the [`CustomLayouts`collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745437%28v=office.14%29.aspx) of the [`SlideMaster` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745484(v=office.14).aspx) of a `Presentation` object. When you create a custom layout, give it a meaningful name. Then you can fetch it from the `CustomLayouts` collection. It appears that Microsoft didn't implement lookup by name, so you will have to iterate through the collection to find the `CustomLayout` object with the right name.

Once you have a reference to the desired `CustomLayout` object, you use the [`AddSlide` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746586(v=office.14).aspx) of the `Slides` collection, which takes a `CustomLayout` object as the second arguments (as opposed to `Slides.Add`, which you used in your question, and which takes a `PpSlideLayout` enumeration value).

Below is a helper method for fetching a custom layout by name, and example of using it as you wanted:

```
Public Function GetLayout( _
    LayoutName As String, _
    Optional ParentPresentation As Presentation = Nothing) As CustomLayout

    If ParentPresentation Is Nothing Then
        Set ParentPresentation = ActivePresentation
    End If

    Dim oLayout As CustomLayout
    For Each oLayout In ParentPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
        If oLayout.Name = LayoutName Then
            Set GetLayout = oLayout
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function

Sub AddCustomSlide()
    Dim oSlides As Slides, oSlide As Slide
    Set oSlides = ActivePresentation.Slides
    Set oSlide = oSlides.AddSlide(oSlides.Count + 1, GetLayout("Smiley"))
End Sub
```

Comment: If I could upvote this five times I would. Excellent answer. Thanks!