# Copy PowerPoint Master Design Using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I am I am trying to import PowerPoint slide design from one ppt to another. While I am able to do that successfully by using Activepresentation.applytemplate, but the problem is when I import the template the design gets applied to the entire presentation.

What i want to do, just import or copy the design from source to destination but not apply. Please advise. Thank you.

Please find the code below

```
Sub ImportTemplate()

ActivePresentation.ApplyTemplate "Source Template Path"

End Sub
```

This imports the template but at the same time applies to the slides also. But I just want to import, not apply.

Comment: @QHarr Please find the code below

Sub ImportTemplate

ActivePresentation.ApplyTemplate &amp;quot;Source Template Path&amp;quot;

End Sub

This imports the template but at the same time applies to the slides also. But I just want to import, not apply.

Comment: Sorry, not sure why the formatting not working

Comment: @QHarr  I have updated my question, but I am using my mobile to post this, so unable to mark it as code. I have tried my best here. Thank you

Comment: If you import it what do you intend to do with? If it is a template it is already available via that path. Surely you would only be bringing it in, in order to apply? Have I missed something?

Comment: @QHarr I want to import the master slide design to my powerpoint and apply the layout to specific slides only. But if I import as I mentioned above, the moment I import, it's gets applied to the entire ppt. Which I don't want

Comment: Sounds like you are after .CustomLayout    for the slide maybe via ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts  ..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147643/how-to-apply-particular-layout-in-powerpoint-using-vba  Seems a bit long winded but could hold the template in one variable and refer to its Designs Slide Master to try and set the custom layout for your activepresentation?   Or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997571/create-a-new-slide-in-vba-for-powerpoint-2010-with-custom-layout-using-master

Comment: @QHarr I had tried this. Didn't work. I found the solution. But I really appreciate your help. My apology if I didn't make myself understandable.

Comment: No it is fine. The links I gave above are about using Designs as you are targeting the slide rather than presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, found the solution.

In place of **ActivePresentation.ApplyTemplate** I used **ActivePresentation.Designs.load** this simply loaded the master design to my ppt but didn't applied to any of the slides.